# object not found - plot.xy

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to run codes that are below. And R gives an Error object '`fireworks`' not found.

Did anyone came cross such Error. How could I fix it?

```
plot.xy(attend/10000~temp|skies+day_night,
    data=dodgers,
    groups=fireworks,
    pch=group.symbols,
    aspect=1,cex=1.5,
    col=group.colors,
    fill=group.fill,
    layout=c(2,2),
    type=c("p","g"),
    xlab="Temperature(Degrees Fahrenheit)", 
    ylab="Attendance(thousands)",
    key=list(space="top", text=list(rev(group.labels),
    col=rev(group.labels)),
    fill=rev(group.fill)))


Eror:
in plot.xy(attend/10000 ~ temp | skies + day_night, data = dodgers,  : 
  object 'fireworks' not found
```

Comment: Your `dodgers` data.frame probably does not contain a column named `fireworks`.

Comment: Perhaps groups wants a character argument (i.e. 'fireworks' instead of fireworks)?  Just as a side comment, you'd be better off using ggplot (package: ggplot2)

Comment: In fact data.frama is looks like this;                      

month day attend day_of_week opponent temp shirt fireworks
APR   10  56000  Tuesday     Pirates  67   No    No 
APR   11  29792  Wednesday   Pirates  58   No    No
APR   12  28328  Thursday    Padres   57   No    Yes

Comment: If your data frame doesn't contain `fireworks`, what do you want to do with it? By which variable do you want to group the data (keep in mind that you have to have the grouping data).

Comment: Thanks for comments  Stephan Kolassa,eamcvey and PavoDive.

I am trying fix it now.

Comment: I got it the; when using xyplot in case of plot.xy it works properly;) thank you guys.